# Java Child parent pojo working with @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring

Need help in uderstanding parent child POJO working with @RequestBody

Parent class is

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CommonInfo {
    
    @NotNull(message = "name is mandatory")
    String name;
    
    @NotNull(message = "pan is mandatory")
    String pan;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPan() {
        return pan;
    }

    public void setPan(String pan) {
        this.pan = pan;
    }
}
```

Child is

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JavaDeveloper extends CommonInfo{
    
    @NotNull(message = "currentPoject is mandatory")
    String currentPoject;
    
    @NotNull(message = "timeline is mandatory")
    String timeline;

    public String getCurrentPoject() {
        return currentPoject;
    }

    public void setCurrentPoject(String currentPoject) {
        this.currentPoject = currentPoject;
    }

    public String getTimeline() {
        return timeline;
    }

    public void setTimeline(String timeline) {
        this.timeline = timeline;
    }
}
```

Controller is

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponsePacket createJavaDeveloper(@Valid @RequestBody JavaDeveloper requestPacket) {
         return new ResponsePacket():
    }
```

my json requestPacket is

```json
{
    "name" : "Smith",
    "pan" : "DFREW1243E",
    "currentPoject" : "Banking project",
    "timeline" : "13-04-2023"
}
```

when i am passing said json packet, only child fields are getting set. I want parent and child both class fields to be set from json packet

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml?
I have tried your code with Spring Boot 3.2.0 and I have not described problem - all fields are set

Comment: Fields are set in parent class also?

Comment: Yes, I returned `requestPacket` in controller `return requestPacket;`
And received the response
`{"name": "Smith","pan": "DFREW1243E","currentPoject": "Banking project","timeline": "13-04-2023"}`. So all fields are populated properly.

Comment: What you have written in child's @toString()

Comment: Nothing. Here is a code https://github.com/stack-overflow-qna/json-child/blob/master/src/main/java/com/romach007/json_child/JavaDeveloper.java

Comment: @RomanCherepanov: Your edit suggestion assumes that GSON is used. But `JsonIgnoreProperties` is an annotation from Jackson. I think you should retract your edit suggestion!

Comment: @IntekhabAlam: Please edit your question and add the tag of the JSON library you are using to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar application and published it [here](https://github.com/stack-overflow-qna/json-child/tree/master)

It uses Spring Boot 3.2.0

I convert `requestPacket` to string using Gson library and return this string as response.

As a result I receive following response:

```json
{
    "currentPoject": "Banking project",
    "timeline": "13-04-2023",
    "name": "Smith",
    "pan": "DFREW1243E"
}
```

This means that all fields are populated properly.

Considering that you are using an old version of the Spring framework, I would advise you to update the version of the Spring framework and Gson library.

To serialize fields in specific order you have several options:

1. create custom `JsonSerializer`
2. use Jackson

### Custom `JsonSerializer`

```java
public class JavaDeveloperJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<JavaDeveloper> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(JavaDeveloper javaDeveloper, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.add("name", context.serialize(javaDeveloper.getName()));
        object.add("pan", context.serialize(javaDeveloper.getPan()));
        object.add("currentProject", context.serialize(javaDeveloper.getCurrentProject()));
        object.add("timeline", context.serialize(javaDeveloper.getTimeline()));
        return object;
    }

}
```

Then use this serializer in constructor:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(JavaDeveloper.class, new JavaDeveloperJsonSerializer()).create();
String response = gson.toJson(requestPacket);
```

### Use Jackson

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUserJackson", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String createJavaDeveloperJackson(@Valid @RequestBody JavaDeveloper requestPacket) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String response = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestPacket);
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is, i have to store request packet in database... And for that i am doing new Gson().toJson(requestPacket)... I am only getting child fields.. i am using spring 4.0

Comment: If i am doing requestPacket.getName() it is showing proper value.. but when i am converting child class in in json (for saving in database) it is only giving child's fields

Comment: I have updated the answer and the source code. All fields are serialised properly. Considering that you are using an old version of the Spring framework, I would advise you to update the version of the Spring framework and Gson library.

Comment: I have upgraded to Spring 5.. now i am getting all fields.. but all parent class fields are coming after child fields... I want parent fields first.... I am using Gson library

Comment: @IntekhabAlam to serialize fields in specific order you need to create custom JsonSerializer. I have updated answer and code repository

Comment: I have approx 50 fields in my actual pojo class

Comment: @IntekhabAlam the second option is to use Jackson for serialization